# How to move particles on mouse hover & restore them to it's actual position

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5-canvas, particles.js

I new to canvas programming. I want create particle background animation for my website. I found a code pen which animate particles in direction. I want to add mouse hover effect to the particle animation like when I mouse hover on particles it should change it's position (collision detection) & when mouse out particle should re-arrange to it's actual position.
I have tried mouse move event but unsuccessful. 
How could I achieve this? any reference will be very useful. Thank you in advance.

```js
// modified version of random-normal
function normalPool(o){var r=0;do{var a=Math.round(normal({mean:o.mean,dev:o.dev}));if(a<o.pool.length&&a>=0)return o.pool[a];r++}while(r<100)}function randomNormal(o){if(o=Object.assign({mean:0,dev:1,pool:[]},o),Array.isArray(o.pool)&&o.pool.length>0)return normalPool(o);var r,a,n,e,l=o.mean,t=o.dev;do{r=(a=2*Math.random()-1)*a+(n=2*Math.random()-1)*n}while(r>=1);return e=a*Math.sqrt(-2*Math.log(r)/r),t*e+l}

const NUM_PARTICLES = 600;
const PARTICLE_SIZE = 1; // View heights
const SPEED = 20000; // Milliseconds

let particles = [];

function rand(low, high) {
  return Math.random() * (high - low) + low;
}

  function getRandomColor() {
   const arr = [{
    r: 215,
    g: 88,
    b: 69,
    a: 1
  }, {
    r: 117,
    g: 161,
    b: 199,
    a: 1
  }]                      
     const randomColor = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
                         return randomColor;
            }
                       
function createParticle(canvas) {
 
  const colour = getRandomColor();
  
  return {
    x: -2,
    y: -2,
    diameter: Math.max(0, randomNormal({ mean: PARTICLE_SIZE, dev: PARTICLE_SIZE / 2 })),
    duration: randomNormal({ mean: SPEED, dev: SPEED * 0.1 }),
    amplitude: randomNormal({ mean: 16, dev: 2 }),
    offsetY: randomNormal({ mean: 0, dev: 10 }),
    arc: Math.PI * 2,
    startTime: performance.now() - rand(0, SPEED),
    colour: `rgba(${colour.r}, ${colour.g}, ${colour.b}, ${colour.a})`,
  }
}

function moveParticle(particle, canvas, time) {
  const progress = ((time - particle.startTime) % particle.duration) / particle.duration;
  return {
    ...particle,
    x: progress,
    y: ((Math.sin(progress * particle.arc) * particle.amplitude) + particle.offsetY),
  };
}

function drawParticle(particle, canvas, ctx) {
  canvas = document.getElementById('particle-canvas');
  const vh = canvas.height / 100;

  ctx.fillStyle = particle.colour;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.ellipse(
    particle.x * canvas.width,
    particle.y * vh + (canvas.height / 2),
    particle.diameter * vh,
    particle.diameter * vh,
    0,
    0,
    2 * Math.PI
  );
  ctx.fill();
}

function draw(time, canvas, ctx) {
  // Move particles
  particles.forEach((particle, index) => {
    particles[index] = moveParticle(particle, canvas, time);
  })

  // Clear the canvas
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // Draw the particles
  particles.forEach((particle) => {
    drawParticle(particle, canvas, ctx);
  })

  // Schedule next frame
  requestAnimationFrame((time) => draw(time, canvas, ctx));
}

function initializeCanvas() {
  let canvas = document.getElementById('particle-canvas');
  canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth * window.devicePixelRatio;
  canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight * window.devicePixelRatio;
  let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
    canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth * window.devicePixelRatio;
    canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight * window.devicePixelRatio;
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  })

  return [canvas, ctx];
}

function startAnimation() {
  const [canvas, ctx] = initializeCanvas();

  // Create a bunch of particles
  for (let i = 0; i < NUM_PARTICLES; i++) {
    particles.push(createParticle(canvas));
  }
  
  requestAnimationFrame((time) => draw(time, canvas, ctx));
};

// Start animation when document is loaded
(function () {
  if (document.readystate !== 'loading') {
    startAnimation();
  } else {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
      startAnimation();
    })
  }
}());
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}

#particle-canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(10, 10, 50) 0%,rgb(60, 10, 60) 100%);
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="particle-canvas"></canvas>
```